# Sound artists using convolution reverb?

Tags: convolution, reverb, sonic, art

Hello,
I am currently searching for artists using the convolution reverb in an artistic, original or crazy way.
If anyone could give me some names or stuff to check out it would be really helpfull!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used machine gun shots, convoluted as a whoosh

Answer (score 0):

There have already been some good discussions about convolution reverb, including some unique methods..

[Understanding Convolution Reverb](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/682/understanding-convolution-reverb)

Comment: I know how convolution work. I was asking if someone knew some artists using it for exemple in sonic arts..

Comment: @Jack Understood.  I saw you were new here, and was pointing you to a potential resource.  As far as artists using convolution reverb, I can't think of any that are vocal about it.. I don't know that you'd be able to tell if it was being used.  http://www.1-1-1-1.net/pages/impulses/index.htm some interesting ones here, if you want to try some on your own.  

Answer (score 0):

I owe @Tim Prebble for this tip, but I recently used Sanatarium from Spirit Canyon Audio http://www.spiritcanyonaudio.com/index.php for a production of Dracula. SCA has some other great, super cheap collections of IRs, but Sanatarium fit the bill for gothic, eerie ambiances. There are dozens of different IRs all organized by approximate "theme" and I just kept experimenting 'til I found what I wanted.

Sanatarium's IR's and a convolution reverb was a total life-saver for me...all for $35.